# Python-Gammu ERROROPENDeVICE

Tags: python, sms, gammu

I installed gammu gammu-smsd and python3-gammu on my raspberry pi and try to send sms via python code which i have as example from the gammu webpage.

From the console i can send a message, so the device is working and the configuration of the /etc/gammu-smsdrc seems to be correct. I configured the /home/user/gammurc with gammu-config with the same device (dev/ttyUSB0) and same Values, but when i try to send a sms with the following python code, which is from the gammu webpage:

```
sm = gammu.StateMachine()
sm.ReadConfig()
sm.Init()

message = {
    'Text': 'python-gammu testing message',
    'SMSC': {'Location': 1},
    'Number': '+420800123465',
}

sm.SendSMS(message)
```

it says:

```
>>> %Run SMS_Neu.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/MyHome/SMS_Neu.py", line 5, in <module>
    sm.Init()
gammu.ERR_DEVICEOPENERROR: {'Text': 'Error opening Device. Unknown, busy or no rights.', 'Where': 'Init', 'Code': 2}
>>>
```

Anybody an idea what i miss or made wrong?

Thanks in forward...

Answer (score 0):

Now i found out, it seems that gammu-smsd is blocking the device. If I stop it with sudo "service gammu-smsd stop", then it works.

I think gammu-smsd is necessary to receive sms? I need to test and I will give response for others with the same problem.